# Opening Scan layout using card.io leads the app to background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, card.io

I am using **card.io SDK** in my android app to scan Credit card number. when the camera opens (Scan layout) to scan the card, the app which is having the libs of card.io went to background not in ios. So the camera is not opening as a part of the app's activity i think. hence my app went to background. Is this possible to open camera (scan layout) using card.io as a part of the app's activity?

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit more detail?  The question is confusing as it is written.

Comment: Hi @JeffBrateman i changed the title and body please review it.