# Cancel button in card.io scanning screen Android

Tags: android, card.io

I'm using card.io on Android. Is it possible to put a cancel button in the scanning view? iOS has that option.

I'm currently passing these extras to the `scanIntent`:

```
public void onScanPress() {
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, true);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_CONFIRMATION, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, card.io relies on the fact that there is a back button (hard or soft).  Therefore, there's no additional cancel button.  Sorry.

Comment: Jeff Can you please see the below question and put your comments . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180632/opening-scan-layout-using-card-io-leads-the-app-to-background